# Use enum descriptions in DataGridComboBox for auto generated DataGrid Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, enums

I have a DataGrid bound on a simple ObservableCollection of objects with some enums and strings.
(5 enums and 2 strings to be excact). Now, two of these enums (which are the same type) need to use their Descriptor to be shown in the comboBox. But I cant figure out how to tell the individual columns to use the description of the enum.

This is my dataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding StartConditions}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStartCondition}">
</DataGrid>
```

And this is the enum with the descriptions I bind.

```
  enum Size
  {
    [Description("8-Bit")]
    EightBit,
    [Description("16-Bit")]
    SixteenBit,
    Bit0,
    Bit1,
    Bit2,
    Bit3,
    Bit4,
    Bit5,
    Bit6,
    Bit7,
    Lower4,
    Upper4
  }
```

And this is how my DataGrid looks.

[image]

The two columns who'd need the description are Size1 and Size2.
The columns are auto generated and I just cant figure out how to use the enum descriptions.

Comment: What .NET Framework version are you using?

Comment: @Herdo I'm using 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible, but a little bit tricky and not very wise in terms of performance. You are going to modify columns generation process to display the correct text.

**First** of all, attach to the [`AutoGeneratingColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event of your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          ...
          AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
</DataGrid>
```

In this handler, you can modify the columns:

```
void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Column contains the generated column
}
```

**Secondly**, you can access the `e.Column` property and apply a `DataTemplate`.
This `DataTemplate` would then use a **converter** for displaying the correct text in the `ComboBoxColumn`. This converter would try to "parse" the enum member attribute as display name, or just display the actual enum value.

**EDIT #1:**

As OP mentioned, `DataGridColumn` doesn't provide a `CellTemplate` property.
Therefore, you have to override the created column in the event handler:

```
var oldColumn = e.Column;
var newColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
// Copy required properties from 'oldColumn' to 'newColumn'

// Create cell template (or load from XAML resources)
var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
// modify template...
newColumn.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;
e.Column = newColumn;
```

Comment: How can I apply a DataTemplate to e.Column? It doesnt give me that choice.